# How to only allow certain users to read Firestore database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a small webapp based on a firestore database and I just want certain users to access (read and write) the data. It may be like 15 or 20 UIDs. I have created a collection -in root level- named "whitelist" and inside it each document has the UID of the user and several fields with the userID, userName and userEmail.

Then I have written my rules as follow:

```
service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && data.child('whitelist').hasChild(auth.uid);
    }   } }
```

However, I have tried with my own user to see if it works and the user is not able to read anything at all even though there is a document within the whitelist collection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can insert them in collection in your database and then in the rules check if it exists in that collection or you can create objects using their UIDs and then allow access only to those which UID matches

Comment: @ErayIsmailov I  have already a collection named users where I have those users. Each one of them is a document in that collection. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is well worth to ensure that the statement `data.child('whitelist').hasChild(auth.uid)` returns `true`.

Also according to [Data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) you should use `resource.data`

> The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. For more information on the `resource` variable, see [the reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource).

You can try adding `resource`:

```
service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.child('whitelist').hasChild(auth.uid);
    }   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will check if the user is authenticated and his UID exists 
// in "haveAccess" collection which must be placed in root. You can use the same for ".write"

".read":"(auth !== null && data.child('haveAccess').hasChild(auth.uid))"
```

You can check the documentation for rules here : [Google Firebase Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax?authuser=0#structuring_your_security_rules)

Comment: I believe that instruction would be for Realtime database and I am using Firestore which is different. I have tried to adapt it to Firestore rules security but it is not working. I just edited the main post to notify what I have done. Thank you though!